# Show dialog or popup after database insertion using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, database, mobile, dialog, webmatrix

I'm using WebMatrix with jQuery Mobile to develop a simple mobile web page that involves some database operations.  One of the requirements is to show an alert-like dialog to inform users how the operation goes.  I've done some researches, but I couldn't find a working solution when it comes to some database operations.  The followings are the best I can do, there seems to be some problem though.

1. The data insertion is successful, but it always goes the redirect in the catch block, ignoring the one in the try block.
2. This is definitely not a good practice.  Can someone give me a direction to implement this more efficiently?

Thanks in advance.

**Default.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";
    Page.Name = "Test Adding Records";
    if (IsPost)
    {
        string strFirst, strSecond;
        strFirst = Request.Form["first"];
        strSecond = Request.Form["second"];

        var database = Database.Open("TestDB");
        string strSql = "INSERT INTO TestTable " +
            "(firstCol, secondCol) " +
            "VALUES(@0, @1);";
        try{
            database.Execute(strSql, strFirst, strSecond);
            Response.Redirect("~/Msg.cshtml?msg=Successfully");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Response.Redirect("~/Msg.cshtml?msg=failed");
        }
    }
}

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Add a Record</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="first">First Column:</label>
                <input type="text" name="first" id="first" value="@Request.Form["first"]" />
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="second">Second Column:</label>
                <input type="text" name="second" id="second" value="@Request.Form["second"]" />
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <input type="submit" value="Add Record" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Msg.cshtml**

```
@{
    string message = Request.QueryString["msg"];
    string previousUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('@message');
            window.location.replace('@previousUrl');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Am I missing the jQuery? I don't see any.

Comment: Indeed.  This is just a simple test of showing dialog.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this small modification

```
    try{
        database.Execute(strSql, strFirst, strSecond);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Response.Redirect("~/Msg.cshtml?msg=failed");
    }
    Response.Redirect("~/Msg.cshtml?msg=Successfully");
```